# Get same range value order by column

Tags: sql, sql-server, gaps-and-islands

I have a table

```
ID Value
1  2
2  3
3  3
4  3
5  2
6  2
7  1
```

I want to group value but still order by ID, like this

```
ID   Value
1    2
2-4  3
5-6  2
7    1
```

How can I do this?

Comment: This is classic gap and island problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
DECLARE @t TABLE (
    ID INT PRIMARY KEY,
    Value INT
)

INSERT INTO @t (ID, Value)
VALUES (1,2),(2,3),(3,3),(4,3),(5,2),(6,2),(7,1)

SELECT 
    ID =
        CASE WHEN mx = mn
            THEN CAST(mx AS VARCHAR(10))
            ELSE CAST(mn AS VARCHAR(10)) + '-' + CAST(mx AS VARCHAR(10))
        END,
    Value
FROM (
    SELECT group_id, mx = MAX(ID), mn = MIN(ID), Value = MAX(Value)
    FROM (
        SELECT
              *
            , group_id =
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ID) -
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Value ORDER BY ID)
        FROM @t
    ) t
    GROUP BY group_id
) t
```

output -

```
ID    Value
----- -----------
1     2
2-4   3
5-6   2
7     1
```